# Use of ajax to get new data in views , rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on Ruby on rails app , basically this is my view

```
<%= @h %>
 // some changes to @h which is n total_span
jQuery.ajax({
data: 'val=' + total_span,
dataType: 'script',
type: 'post',
url: "/portfolio/slide_change"
});
```

Slide_change is this:

```
j=params[:val]
g=TargetPortfolio.new
@h=g.finding_the_concerned_id(j)  
render "target_port"
```

target_port -name of view file.

I am not getting the refreshed value of @h , any guesses where i am wrong.
But in my page i am not getting the refreshed value of @h ,

Comment: Why would you? `@h` is executed *on the server* and won't be touched again until that code is executed *on the server* again.

Comment: But the code gets executed with jquery,ajax ,the method slide_change is called. If i am wrong , kindly clarify.

Comment: Yes, you're routing the ajax call to whatever `slide_change` is. *BUT IT'S AJAX*, and nothing it does will affect the `<%= @h %>` code on the same page, because that's *already been executed on the server side*.

Comment: So what is the right way to do this?